# How to generate a random string of a fixed length in Go?

Tags: string, random, go

I want a random string of characters only (uppercase or lowercase), no numbers, in Go. What is the fastest and simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1264, accepted):

[Paul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892986/1114274) provides a *simple*, general solution.

The question asks for the *"the fastest and simplest way"*. Let's address the *fastest* part too. We'll arrive at our final, fastest code in an iterative manner. Benchmarking each iteration can be found at the end of the answer.

All the solutions and the benchmarking code can be found on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KcuJ_2c_NDj). The code on the Playground is a test file, not an executable. You have to save it into a file named `XX_test.go` and run it with

```
go test -bench . -benchmem
```

**Foreword**:

> The fastest solution is not a go-to solution if you just need a random string. For that, Paul's solution is perfect. This is if performance does matter. Although the first 2 steps (**Bytes** and **Remainder**) might be an acceptable compromise: they do improve performance by like 50% (see exact numbers in the **II. Benchmark** section), and they don't increase complexity significantly.

Having said that, even if you don't need the fastest solution, reading through this answer might be adventurous and educational.

### I. Improvements

#### 1. Genesis (Runes)

As a reminder, the original, general solution we're improving is this:

```
func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

var letterRunes = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

func RandStringRunes(n int) string {
    b := make([]rune, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letterRunes[rand.Intn(len(letterRunes))]
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

#### 2. Bytes

If the characters to choose from and assemble the random string contains only the uppercase and lowercase letters of the English alphabet, we can work with bytes only because the English alphabet letters map to bytes 1-to-1 in the UTF-8 encoding (which is how Go stores strings).

So instead of:

```
var letters = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

we can use:

```
var letters = []byte("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

Or even better:

```
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Now this is already a big improvement: we could achieve it to be a `const` (there are `string` constants but [there are no slice constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29365828/1705598)). As an extra gain, the expression `len(letters)` will also be a `const`! (The expression `len(s)` is constant if `s` is a string constant.)

And at what cost? Nothing at all. `string`s can be indexed which indexes its bytes, perfect, exactly what we want.

Our next destination looks like this:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

func RandStringBytes(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letterBytes[rand.Intn(len(letterBytes))]
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

#### 3. Remainder

Previous solutions get a random number to designate a random letter by calling [`rand.Intn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn) which delegates to [`Rand.Intn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Intn) which delegates to [`Rand.Int31n()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Int31n).

This is much slower compared to [`rand.Int63()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int63) which produces a random number with 63 random bits.

So we could simply call `rand.Int63()` and use the remainder after dividing by `len(letterBytes)`:

```
func RandStringBytesRmndr(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letterBytes[rand.Int63() % int64(len(letterBytes))]
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

This works and is significantly faster, the disadvantage is that the probability of all the letters will not be exactly the same (assuming `rand.Int63()` produces all 63-bit numbers with equal probability). Although the distortion is extremely small as the number of letters `52` is much-much smaller than `1<<63 - 1`, so in practice this is perfectly fine.

<sup>To make this understand easier: let's say you want a random number in the range of `0..5`. Using 3 random bits, this would produce the numbers `0..1` with double probability than from the range `2..5`. Using 5 random bits, numbers in range `0..1` would occur with `6/32` probability and numbers in range `2..5` with `5/32` probability which is now closer to the desired. Increasing the number of bits makes this less significant, when reaching 63 bits, it is negligible.</sup>

#### 4. Masking

Building on the previous solution, we can maintain the equal distribution of letters by using only as many of the lowest bits of the random number as many is required to represent the number of letters. So for example if we have 52 letters, it requires 6 bits to represent it: `52 = 110100b`. So we will only use the lowest 6 bits of the number returned by `rand.Int63()`. And to maintain equal distribution of letters, we only "accept" the number if it falls in the range `0..len(letterBytes)-1`. If the lowest bits are greater, we discard it and query a new random number.

Note that the chance of the lowest bits to be greater than or equal to `len(letterBytes)` is less than `0.5` in general (`0.25` on average), which means that even if this would be the case, repeating this "rare" case decreases the chance of not finding a good number. After `n` repetition, the chance that we still don't have a good index is much less than `pow(0.5, n)`, and this is just an upper estimation. In case of 52 letters the chance that the 6 lowest bits are not good is only `(64-52)/64 = 0.19`; which means for example that chances to not have a good number after 10 repetition is `1e-8`.

So here is the solution:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
)

func RandStringBytesMask(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; {
        if idx := int(rand.Int63() & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i++
        }
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

#### 5. Masking Improved

The previous solution only uses the lowest 6 bits of the 63 random bits returned by `rand.Int63()`. This is a waste as getting the random bits is the slowest part of our algorithm.

If we have 52 letters, that means 6 bits code a letter index. So 63 random bits can designate `63/6 = 10` different letter indices. Let's use all those 10:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

func RandStringBytesMaskImpr(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A rand.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax letters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, rand.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = rand.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}
```

#### 6. Source

The **Masking Improved** is pretty good, not much we can improve on it. We could, but not worth the complexity.

Now let's find something else to improve. **The source of random numbers.**

There is a [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) package which provides a [`Read(b []byte)`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read) function, so we could use that to get as many bytes with a single call as many we need. This wouldn't help in terms of performance as `crypto/rand` implements a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator so it's much slower.

So let's stick to the `math/rand` package. The `rand.Rand` uses a [`rand.Source`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Source) as the source of random bits. `rand.Source` is an interface which specifies a `Int63() int64` method: exactly and the only thing we needed and used in our latest solution.

So we don't really need a `rand.Rand` (either explicit or the global, shared one of the `rand` package), a `rand.Source` is perfectly enough for us:

```
var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())

func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}
```

Also note that this last solution doesn't require you to initialize (seed) the global `Rand` of the `math/rand` package as that is not used (and our `rand.Source` is properly initialized / seeded).

One more thing to note here: package doc of `math/rand` states:

> The default Source is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

So the default source is slower than a `Source` that may be obtained by `rand.NewSource()`, because the default source has to provide safety under concurrent access / use, while `rand.NewSource()` does not offer this (and thus the `Source` returned by it is more likely to be faster).

#### 7. Utilizing `strings.Builder`

All previous solutions return a `string` whose content is first built in a slice (`[]rune` in **Genesis**, and `[]byte` in subsequent solutions), and then converted to `string`. This final conversion has to make a copy of the slice's content, because `string` values are immutable, and if the conversion would not make a copy, it could not be guaranteed that the string's content is not modified via its original slice. For details, see [How to convert utf8 string to []byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460750/how-to-convert-utf8-string-to-byte/41460993#41460993) and [golang: []byte(string) vs []byte(*string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344).

[Go 1.10 introduced `strings.Builder`.](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#strings) [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) is a new type we can use to build contents of a `string` similar to [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer). Internally it uses a `[]byte` to build the content, and when we're done, we can obtain the final `string` value using its [`Builder.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.String) method. But what's cool in it is that it does this without performing the copy we just talked about above. It dares to do so because the byte slice used to build the string's content is not exposed, so it is guaranteed that no one can modify it unintentionally or maliciously to alter the produced "immutable" string.

So our next idea is to not build the random string in a slice, but with the help of a `strings.Builder`, so once we're done, we can obtain and return the result without having to make a copy of it. This may help in terms of speed, and it will definitely help in terms of memory usage and allocations.

```
func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrcSB(n int) string {
    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.Grow(n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            sb.WriteByte(letterBytes[idx])
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return sb.String()
}
```

Do note that after creating a new `strings.Buidler`, we called its [`Builder.Grow()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.Grow) method, making sure it allocates a big-enough internal slice (to avoid reallocations as we add the random letters).

#### 8. "Mimicing" `strings.Builder` with package `unsafe`

`strings.Builder` builds the string in an internal `[]byte`, the same as we did ourselves. So basically doing it via a `strings.Builder` has some overhead, the only thing we switched to `strings.Builder` for is to avoid the final copying of the slice.

`strings.Builder` avoids the final copy by using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/):

```
// String returns the accumulated string.
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

The thing is, we can also do this ourselves, too. So the idea here is to switch back to building the random string in a `[]byte`, but when we're done, don't convert it to `string` to return, but do an unsafe conversion: obtain a `string` which points to our byte slice as the string data.

This is how it can be done:

```
func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrcUnsafe(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}
```

#### (9. Using `rand.Read()`)

[Go 1.7 added](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#math_rand) a [`rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read) function and a [`Rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Read) method. We should be tempted to use these to read as many bytes as we need in one step, in order to achieve better performance.

There is one small "problem" with this: how many bytes do we need? We could say: as many as the number of output letters. We would think this is an upper estimation, as a letter index uses less than 8 bits (1 byte). But at this point we are already doing worse (as getting the random bits is the "hard part"), and we're getting more than needed.

Also note that to maintain equal distribution of all letter indices, there might be some "garbage" random data that we won't be able to use, so we would end up skipping some data, and thus end up short when we go through all the byte slice. We would need to further get more random bytes, "recursively". And now we're even losing the "single call to `rand` package" advantage...

We could "somewhat" optimize the usage of the random data we acquire from `math.Rand()`. We may estimate how many bytes (bits) we'll need. 1 letter requires `letterIdxBits` bits, and we need `n` letters, so we need `n * letterIdxBits / 8.0` bytes rounding up. We can calculate the probability of a random index not being usable (see above), so we could request more that will "more likely" be enough (if it turns out it's not, we repeat the process). We can process the byte slice as a "bit stream" for example, for which we have a nice 3rd party lib: [`github.com/icza/bitio`](https://github.com/icza/bitio) (disclosure: I'm the author).

But Benchmark code still shows we're not winning. Why is it so?

The answer to the last question is because `rand.Read()` uses a loop and keeps calling `Source.Int63()` until it fills the passed slice. Exactly what the `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` solution does, *without* the intermediate buffer, and without the added complexity. That's why `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` remains on the throne. Yes, `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` uses an unsynchronized `rand.Source` unlike `rand.Read()`. But the reasoning still applies; and which is proven if we use `Rand.Read()` instead of `rand.Read()` (the former is also unsynchronzed).

### II. Benchmark

All right, it's time for benchmarking the different solutions.

Moment of truth:

```
BenchmarkRunes-4                     2000000    723 ns/op   96 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytes-4                     3000000    550 ns/op   32 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesRmndr-4                3000000    438 ns/op   32 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesMask-4                 3000000    534 ns/op   32 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesMaskImpr-4            10000000    176 ns/op   32 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesMaskImprSrc-4         10000000    139 ns/op   32 B/op   2 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesMaskImprSrcSB-4       10000000    134 ns/op   16 B/op   1 allocs/op
BenchmarkBytesMaskImprSrcUnsafe-4   10000000    115 ns/op   16 B/op   1 allocs/op
```

Just by switching from runes to bytes, we immediately have **24%** performance gain, and memory requirement drops to **one third**.

Getting rid of `rand.Intn()` and using `rand.Int63()` instead gives another **20%** boost.

Masking (and repeating in case of big indices) slows down a little (due to repetition calls): **-22%**...

But when we make use of all (or most) of the 63 random bits (10 indices from one `rand.Int63()` call): that speeds up big time: **3 times**.

If we settle with a (non-default, new) `rand.Source` instead of `rand.Rand`, we again gain **21%.**

If we utilize `strings.Builder`, we gain a tiny **3.5%** in *speed*, but we also achieved **50%** reduction in memory usage and allocations! That's nice!

Finally if we dare to use package `unsafe` instead of `strings.Builder`, we again gain a nice **14%**.

Comparing the final to the initial solution: `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrcUnsafe()` is **6.3 times faster** than `RandStringRunes()`, uses **one sixth** memory and **half as few allocations**. Mission accomplished.

Comment: How unique is the string that generated by this method?

Comment: @dev-jim The "quality" of the above solutions depends on the "randomness" of `math.Random`. If we assume it's perfectly random, then the above solutions generate any possible random strings (with the given length) with equal probability. This is the perfect / optimal outcome.

Comment: It seems the probability of duplication is too high.

Comment: @Mystic Then use another source of random numbers, e.g.`crypto/rand`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that this func does not support in concurrency. My BenchmarkCheckDuplication is running in Concurrency. Every few hundred runs, it will gen a duplicate.

Comment: @Mystic Yes, this is not concurrency safe as the source used it not safe. If you need a concurrency safe solution, create and use a designated source for each.

Answer (score 223):

You can just write code for it. This code can be a little simpler if you want to rely on the letters all being single bytes when encoded in UTF-8.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

var letters = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

func randSeq(n int) string {
    b := make([]rune, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letters[rand.Intn(len(letters))]
    }
    return string(b)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(randSeq(10))
}
```

Comment: For a hard-to-guess secret--a password, a crypto key, etc.--never use `math/rand`; use `crypto/rand` (like @Not_A_Golfer's option 1) instead.

Comment: Note that if you're trying the above program with seed, on go playground, it will return same result all the time. I was trying it out on playground and after a some time realized this. It worked fine otherwise for me. Hope it saves someones time :)

Comment: "rand.Seed has been deprecated since Go 1.20 and an alternative has been available since Go 1.0: Programs that call Seed and then expect a specific sequence of results from the global random source (using functions such as Int) can be broken when a dependency changes how much it consumes from the global random source. (...)" taken from [(SA1019) go-staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks/#SA1019) and here is an [example how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75597325/1977012)

Answer (score 35):

Use package [uniuri](https://github.com/dchest/uniuri), which generates cryptographically secure uniform (unbiased) strings.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package

Comment: Thanks for this.  While I appreciate the ample detail in other answers, your answer provided a quick practical way to generate the short random string I wanted.

Answer (score 31):

Simple solution for you, with least duplicate result:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func randomString(length int) string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    b := make([]byte, length+2)
    rand.Read(b)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)[2 : length+2]
}
```

Check it out in the [PlayGround](https://go.dev/play/p/M83MV42B8dY)

Comment: Don't seed for every call! You should seed once at program startup.

Answer (score 20):

Two possible options (there might be more of course):

1. You can use the `crypto/rand` package that supports reading random byte arrays (from /dev/urandom) and is geared towards cryptographic random generation. see http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#example_Read . It might be slower than normal pseudo-random number generation though.
2. Take a random number and hash it using md5 or something like this.

Answer (score 14):

If you want *cryptographically secure* random numbers, and the exact charset is flexible (say, base64 is fine), you can calculate exactly what the length of random characters you need from the desired output size.

Base 64 text is 1/3 longer than base 256. (2^8 vs 2^6; 8bits/6bits = 1.333 ratio)

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "math"
)

func randomBase64String(l int) string {
    buff := make([]byte, int(math.Ceil(float64(l)/float64(1.33333333333))))
    rand.Read(buff)
    str := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(buff)
    return str[:l] // strip 1 extra character we get from odd length results
}
```

Note: you can also use RawStdEncoding if you prefer + and / characters to - and _

If you want hex, base 16 is 2x longer than base 256. (2^8 vs 2^4; 8bits/4bits = 2x ratio)

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/hex"
    "math"
)


func randomBase16String(l int) string {
    buff := make([]byte, int(math.Ceil(float64(l)/2)))
    rand.Read(buff)
    str := hex.EncodeToString(buff)
    return str[:l] // strip 1 extra character we get from odd length results
}
```

However, you could extend this to any arbitrary character set if you have a base256 to baseN encoder for your character set. You can do the same size calculation with how many bits are needed to represent your character set. The ratio calculation for any arbitrary charset is: `ratio = 8 / log2(len(charset))`).

Though both of these solutions are secure, simple, should be fast, and don't waste your crypto entropy pool.

Here's the playground showing it works for any size. https://play.golang.org/p/_yF_xxXer0Z

Comment: worth mentioning that Go Playground always returns the same random number, so you won't see in there different random strings at different executions of that code

Comment: The randomBase64String() func is really good answer, because it combines the high-density base64 encoding with   crypto/rand data generation. BUT, it has a bug. When you ask for 3 characters, it will generate two random bytes, only giving you 16 bits of entropy, not 18 bits of entropy.  I suggest you use buff:=make([]byte, ((6*l)+7)/8), if you want all the bits to be random (without generating excess random entropy, either).   This playground snippet shows the original example fails to generate sufficient bits to fill out the base64 frequently. https://play.golang.org/p/uVLosTt1jyo

Comment: Thanks @Cameron, I think math.Ceil will avoid this problem. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 12):

Another version, inspired from [generate password in JavaScript crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540480/1099314):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-"

func shortID(length int) string {
    ll := len(chars)
    b := make([]byte, length)
    rand.Read(b) // generates len(b) random bytes
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        b[i] = chars[int(b[i])%ll]
    }
    return string(b)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(shortID(18))
    fmt.Println(shortID(18))
    fmt.Println(shortID(18))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Following `icza's` wonderfully explained solution, here is a modification of it that uses `crypto/rand` instead of `math/rand`.

```
const (
    letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" // 52 possibilities
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent 64 possibilities / indexes
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
)

func SecureRandomAlphaString(length int) string {

    result := make([]byte, length)
    bufferSize := int(float64(length)*1.3)
    for i, j, randomBytes := 0, 0, []byte{}; i < length; j++ {
        if j%bufferSize == 0 {
            randomBytes = SecureRandomBytes(bufferSize)
        }
        if idx := int(randomBytes[j%length] & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            result[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i++
        }
    }

    return string(result)
}

// SecureRandomBytes returns the requested number of bytes using crypto/rand
func SecureRandomBytes(length int) []byte {
    var randomBytes = make([]byte, length)
    _, err := rand.Read(randomBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to generate random bytes")
    }
    return randomBytes
}
```

If you want a more generic solution, that allows you to pass in the slice of character bytes to create the string out of, you can try using this:

```
// SecureRandomString returns a string of the requested length,
// made from the byte characters provided (only ASCII allowed).
// Uses crypto/rand for security. Will panic if len(availableCharBytes) > 256.
func SecureRandomString(availableCharBytes string, length int) string {

    // Compute bitMask
    availableCharLength := len(availableCharBytes)
    if availableCharLength == 0 || availableCharLength > 256 {
        panic("availableCharBytes length must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 256")
    }
    var bitLength byte
    var bitMask byte
    for bits := availableCharLength - 1; bits != 0; {
        bits = bits >> 1
        bitLength++
    }
    bitMask = 1<<bitLength - 1

    // Compute bufferSize
    bufferSize := length + length / 3

    // Create random string
    result := make([]byte, length)
    for i, j, randomBytes := 0, 0, []byte{}; i < length; j++ {
        if j%bufferSize == 0 {
            // Random byte buffer is empty, get a new one
            randomBytes = SecureRandomBytes(bufferSize)
        }
        // Mask bytes to get an index into the character slice
        if idx := int(randomBytes[j%length] & bitMask); idx < availableCharLength {
            result[i] = availableCharBytes[idx]
            i++
        }
    }

    return string(result)
}
```

If you want to pass in your own source of randomness, it would be trivial to modify the above to accept an `io.Reader` instead of using `crypto/rand`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my way ) Use math rand or crypto rand as you wish.

```
func randStr(len int) string {
    buff := make([]byte, len)
    rand.Read(buff)
    str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buff)
    // Base 64 can be longer than len
    return str[:len]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use google's uuid library in a lot of my projects, which enables me to easily do this:

```
uuid.NewString()[:length]
```

It at least checks the box for simplest.

https://go.dev/play/p/5sWDsGqglAi

Comment: This does not answer the original question though. It produces numbers and lowercase letters from a-f. I do this myself if I want just a string with random characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and performant solution.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "unsafe"
    "fmt"
)

var alphabet = []byte("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

func main() {
    fmt.Println(generate(16))
}

func generate(size int) string {
    b := make([]byte, size)
    rand.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        b[i] = alphabet[b[i] % byte(len(alphabet))]
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}
```

Benchmark

```
Benchmark  95.2 ns/op      16 B/op      1 allocs/op
```

Comment: It's not cryptographically secure. Check the distribution of your letters.

Comment: @eik: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Mitar the problem is that using a modulo like this causes the distribution to be not quite uniform, but slightly biased. You can read more here: https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2020/07/28/the-definitive-guide-to-modulo-bias-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Answer (score 2):

```
func Rand(n int) (str string) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    rand.Read(b)
    str = fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
    return
}
```

Comment: Why it generates n*2 `[]byte`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this if it takes an option to capitalize or not

```
func randomString(length int, upperCase bool) string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    var alphabet string

    if upperCase {
        alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    } else {
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    }

    var sb strings.Builder

    l := len(alphabet)

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        c := alphabet[rand.Intn(l)]
        sb.WriteByte(c)
    }

    return sb.String()
}
```

and like this if you don't need capital letters

```
func randomString(length int) string {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

        var alphabet string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        var sb strings.Builder

        l := len(alphabet)

        for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
                c := alphabet[rand.Intn(l)]
                sb.WriteByte(c)
        }

        return sb.String()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add a few characters to your pool of allowed characters, you can make the code work with anything which provides random bytes through a io.Reader. Here we are using `crypto/rand`.

```
// len(encodeURL) == 64. This allows (x <= 265) x % 64 to have an even
// distribution.
const encodeURL = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"

// A helper function create and fill a slice of length n with characters from
// a-zA-Z0-9_-. It panics if there are any problems getting random bytes.
func RandAsciiBytes(n int) []byte {
    output := make([]byte, n)

    // We will take n bytes, one byte for each character of output.
    randomness := make([]byte, n)

    // read all random
    _, err := rand.Read(randomness)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // fill output
    for pos := range output {
        // get random item
        random := uint8(randomness[pos])

        // random % 64
        randomPos := random % uint8(len(encodeURL))

        // put into output
        output[pos] = encodeURL[randomPos]
    }

    return output
}
```

Comment: why is `random % 64` necessary?

Comment: Because `len(encodeURL) == 64`. If `random % 64` wasn't done, `randomPos` could be >= 64 and cause an out of bounds panic at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code which I used to generate certificate number in my app.

```
func GenerateCertificateNumber() string {
    CertificateLength := 7
    t := time.Now().String()
    CertificateHash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(t), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Make a Regex we only want letters and numbers
    reg, err := regexp.Compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    processedString := reg.ReplaceAllString(string(CertificateHash), "")
    fmt.Println(string(processedString))

    CertificateNumber := strings.ToUpper(string(processedString[len(processedString)-CertificateLength:]))
    fmt.Println(CertificateNumber)
    return CertificateNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to [`icza's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) brilliant solution, below I am using [`rand.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#Reader)

```
func RandStringBytesMaskImprRandReaderUnsafe(length uint) (string, error) {
    const (
        charset     = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        charIdxBits = 6                  // 6 bits to represent a letter index
        charIdxMask = 1<<charIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as charIdxBits
        charIdxMax  = 63 / charIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
    )

    buffer := make([]byte, length)
    charsetLength := len(charset)
    max := big.NewInt(int64(1 << uint64(charsetLength)))

    limit, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, max)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    for index, cache, remain := int(length-1), limit.Int64(), charIdxMax; index >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            limit, err = rand.Int(rand.Reader, max)
            if err != nil {
                return "", err
            }

            cache, remain = limit.Int64(), charIdxMax
        }

        if idx := int(cache & charIdxMask); idx < charsetLength {
            buffer[index] = charset[idx]
            index--
        }

        cache >>= charIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buffer)), nil
}


func BenchmarkBytesMaskImprRandReaderUnsafe(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()

    const length = 16

    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        for pb.Next() {
            RandStringBytesMaskImprRandReaderUnsafe(length)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rand.Int` from `math/rand` things are quite easy now:

```golang
import "math/rand"

func randStr(length uint) string {
    bytes := make([]byte, int(length))
    for i := uint(0); i < length; i++ {
        bytes[i] = byte('!' + rand.Intn('~'-'!'))
    }
    return string(bytes)
}
```

Can limit to only ascii letters with `byte('a' + rand.Intn('z'-'a'))`

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
    korzhao
*/

package rand

import (
    crand "crypto/rand"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

// Doesn't share the rand library globally, reducing lock contention
type Rand struct {
    Seed int64
    Pool *sync.Pool
}

var (
    MRand    = NewRand()
    randlist = []byte("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")
)

// init random number generator
func NewRand() *Rand {
    p := &sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} {
        return rand.New(rand.NewSource(getSeed()))
    },
    }
    mrand := &Rand{
        Pool: p,
    }
    return mrand
}

// get the seed
func getSeed() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano()
}

func (s *Rand) getrand() *rand.Rand {
    return s.Pool.Get().(*rand.Rand)
}
func (s *Rand) putrand(r *rand.Rand) {
    s.Pool.Put(r)
}

// get a random number
func (s *Rand) Intn(n int) int {
    r := s.getrand()
    defer s.putrand(r)

    return r.Intn(n)
}

//  bulk get random numbers
func (s *Rand) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    r := s.getrand()
    defer s.putrand(r)

    return r.Read(p)
}

func CreateRandomString(len int) string {
    b := make([]byte, len)
    _, err := MRand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
        b[i] = randlist[b[i]%(62)]
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
}
```

24.0 ns/op            16 B/op          1 allocs/

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Although you added a code snippet, your answer doesn't include any context about "how it works" or "why this is the way its done". Also please remember the question is asked in English so your comments should also be in English.

Answer (score -3):

```
const (
    chars       = "0123456789_abcdefghijkl-mnopqrstuvwxyz" //ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    charsLen    = len(chars)
    mask        = 1<<6 - 1
)

var rng = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())

// RandStr 返回指定长度的随机字符串
func RandStr(ln int) string {
    /* chars 38个字符
     * rng.Int63() 每次产出64bit的随机数,每次我们使用6bit(2^6=64) 可以使用10次
     */
    buf := make([]byte, ln)
    for idx, cache, remain := ln-1, rng.Int63(), 10; idx >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = rng.Int63(), 10
        }
        buf[idx] = chars[int(cache&mask)%charsLen]
        cache >>= 6
        remain--
        idx--
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))
}
```

BenchmarkRandStr16-8    20000000            68.1 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op

Answer (score -3):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// customEncodeURL is like `bas64.encodeURL` 
// except its made up entirely of uppercase characters:
const customEncodeURL = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL"

// Random generates a random string.
// It is not cryptographically secure.
func Random(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    _, _ = rand.Read(b) // docs say that it always returns a nil error.

    customEncoding := base64.NewEncoding(customEncodeURL).WithPadding(base64.NoPadding)
    return customEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Random(16))
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is not cryptographically secure.