# Generate 6-digit Verification Code with Golang?

Tags: go

Generate 6-digit code for phone verification,
The following is a very simple approach that I have used

```
package main

import ( 
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)        

var randowCodes = [...]byte{
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
}        

func main() {
    var r *rand.Rand = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        var pwd []byte = make([]byte, 6)

        for j := 0; j < 6; j++ {
            index := r.Int() % len(randowCodes)

            pwd[j] = randowCodes[index]
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(pwd))                                                                  
    }    
}
```

Do you have a better way to do this？

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use "crypto/rand" package: which implements a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator. (try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QJ08lYgT3a)):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(EncodeToString(6))
    }
}

func EncodeToString(max int) string {
    b := make([]byte, max)
    n, err := io.ReadAtLeast(rand.Reader, b, max)
    if n != max {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        b[i] = table[int(b[i])%len(table)]
    }
    return string(b)
}

var table = [...]byte{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'}
```

output:

```
640166
195174
221966
```

And see: [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang)

Comment: The results are no longer random due to the random byte being mod by %10.
It is much more likely to see digit 0 to 5 than 6 to 9 because 256 is not evenly divisible by the modulus, the max value is 255%10 = 5 which means for a complete byte, 0-5 appears 26 times each but digits 6-9 appear only 25 times.

Comment: this is generating same numbers on each run, not dynamic.

Answer (score 9):

I've forked user6169399's answer, using `crypto/rand` with const string and small modifications, this is the result:

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
)

const otpChars = "1234567890"

func GenerateOTP(length int) (string, error) {
    buffer := make([]byte, length)
    _, err := rand.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    otpCharsLength := len(otpChars)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        buffer[i] = otpChars[int(buffer[i])%otpCharsLength]
    }

    return string(buffer), nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To account for the observation given by [@Tom Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131005/tom-anderson), a more appropriate answer using real uniform distribution and a simpler code would be:

```golang
func GenerateOTP(maxDigits uint32) string {
    bi, err := rand.Int(
        rand.Reader,
        big.NewInt(int64(math.Pow(10, float64(maxDigits)))),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%0*d", maxDigits, bi)
}
```

[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gN4xXdcLxKu)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rand.Int()` from `crypto/rand` to also generate randomness

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
)

func GenerateOTPCode(length int) (string, error) {
    seed := "012345679"
    byteSlice := make([]byte, length)

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        max := big.NewInt(int64(len(seed)))
        num, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, max)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        byteSlice[i] = seed[num.Int64()]
    }

    return string(byteSlice), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make use of math/rand:

> ```
> func genCaptchaCode() string {
>     r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
>
>     var codes [6]byte
>     for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
>         codes[i] = uint8(48 + r.Intn(10))
>     }
>
>     return string(codes[:])
> }
> ```

2. make use of crypto/rand (more security):

> ```
> func genCaptchaCode() (string, error) {
>     codes := make([]byte, 6)
>     if _, err := rand.Read(codes); err != nil {
>         return "", err
>     }
>
>     for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
>         codes[i] = uint8(48 + (codes[i] % 10))
>     }
>
>     return string(codes), nil
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the easiest way:

```
// generate new recovery code
t := fmt.Sprint(time.Now().Nanosecond())

fmt.Println(t[:6])
```

output:

```
524339
743142
243470
```

function use:

```
func GenerateCode() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(time.Now().Nanosecond())[:6]
}
```

output:

```
302663
477258
678557
```

Comment: This code is not correct.

Comment: @Manassé I made a module based this function. Checkout README and use if you want https://github.com/nanorand/nanorand

Comment: i understand the logic behind that function but the actual code is not correct (I guess you mean something like [length - 6:] instead of [:6]).

Comment: @Manassé unfortunately not, because sometimes time.Now() gives length of 8 and sometimes length of 7 and it's unpredictable, but [:6] and [:7] (with 7 limit) it works fine

Comment: just the length of nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

I needed a bit simpler and flat solution so I came up with this

```golang
// Since Go 1.20 rand.Seed() deprecated

rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

// generates a random number in the range of [0, 900000)
// We add 100000 to the result to ensure the minimum value is 100000
r := rand.Intn(900000) + 100000

fmt.Println(r)
```

**a side note: `rand.Intn(900000)` never generates `900000` the max number is `899999` so the code never generates 1,000,000**