# How to generate unique random alphanumeric tokens in Golang?

Tags: go, token

For a RESTful backend API, I want to generate **unique** url tokens to be used to authenticate users.

The unique data provided at registration to generate tokens are email addresses. But after generating tokens and sending that to the users, I don't need to decrypt received tokens to get email or other information. So the encryption can be one-way.

Initially I used bcrypt to do so:

```
func GenerateToken(email string) string {
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(email), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hash to store:", string(hash))

    return string(hash)

}
```

But since the tokens come as a url parameter (like `/api/path/to/{token}`) I can not use [bcrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) because it generates tokens containing `/` like this:

`"$2a$10$NebCQ8BD7xOa82nkzRGA9OEh./zhBOPcuV98vpOKBKK6ZTFuHtqlK"`

which will break the routing.

So I'm wondering what is the best way to generate some unique 16-32 character alphanumeric tokens based on emails in Golang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang)

Comment: @AlexK. The difference is that I want the token to be not only random, but also unique.

Comment: You may use URL-safe Base64 encoding on any random data. See the exported `encoding/base64/URLEncoding` variable. Using the output of that, you can safely include it in URLs.

Comment: If you can generate a unique number for each user, then you can use a URL safe version of base 64.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to simply urlencode that string?

And shouldn't it be possible for anyone to generate a token for anyone else with that algorithm ?

Comment: @icza Can you elaborate your answer in a code snippet please?

Answer (score 22):

As it was already mentioned you are doing it wrong and this is super insecure.

1. Generate secure token using crypto package. This token completely random and not associated with any email.

```golang
func GenerateSecureToken(length int) string {
    b := make([]byte, length)
    if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    return hex.EncodeToString(b)
}
```

2. Create database table which maps this token to user identifier and during API request validate it.

Comment: but this is super expensive as you need to store all that data....

Comment: Why is this super insecure? Predictability?

Comment: How long it should be?

Answer (score 7):

#### Option 1: md5 hash the bcrypt output

Props to OP for mostly answering his own question :)

I think it'll satisfy everything you're looking for (32-character length):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

// GenerateToken returns a unique token based on the provided email string
func GenerateToken(email string) string {
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(email), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hash to store:", string(hash))

    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write(hash)
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("token:", GenerateToken("bob@webserver.com"))
}
```

> $ go run main.go
>
> Hash to store: $2a$10$B23cv7lDpbY3iVvfZ7GYE.e4691ow8i7l6CQXkmz315fbg4jLzoue
>
> token: 90a514ab93e2c32fdd1072154b26a100

---

Below are 2 of my previous suggestions that I doubt will work better for you, but could be helpful for others to consider.

---

#### Option 2: base64

In the past, I've used base64 encoding to make tokens more portable after encryption/hashing. Here's a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

// GenerateToken returns a unique token based on the provided email string
func GenerateToken(email string) string {
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(email), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hash to store:", string(hash))

    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(hash)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("token:", GenerateToken("bob@webserver.com"))
}
```

> $ go run main.go
>
> Hash to store: $2a$10$cbVMU9U665VSqpfwrNZWOeU5cIDOe5iBJ8ZVa2yJCTsnk9MEZHvRq
>
> token: JDJhJDEwJGNiVk1VOVU2NjVWU3FwZndyTlpXT2VVNWNJRE9lNWlCSjhaVmEyeUpDVHNuazlNRVpIdlJx

As you can see, this unfortunately *doesn't* provide you with a 16-32 character length. If you're okay with the length being 80 long, then this might work for you.

---

#### Option 3: url path/query escapes

I also tried url.PathEscape and url.QueryEscape to be thorough. While they have the same problem as the base64 example (length, though a bit shorter), at least they "should" work in the path:

```
// GenerateToken returns a unique token based on the provided email string
func GenerateToken(email string) string {
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(email), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hash to store:", string(hash))

    fmt.Println("url.PathEscape:", url.PathEscape(string(hash)))
    fmt.Println("url.QueryEscape:", url.QueryEscape(string(hash)))

    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(hash)
}
```

> url.PathEscape: $2a$10$wx1UL6%2F7RD6sFq7Bzpgcc.ibFSW114Tf6A521wRh9rVy8dp%2Fa82x2
>   url.QueryEscape: %242a%2410%24wx1UL6%2F7RD6sFq7Bzpgcc.ibFSW114Tf6A521wRh9rVy8dp%2Fa82x2

Comment: What about feeding the result into a MD5 to shorten the resulting token, like this:  `hasher := md5.New();
 hasher.Write([]byte(token));
 return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))` ?

Comment: nice idea, @Karlom - I'll try that out also

Comment: consider adding time span validity https://github.com/anacrolix/dht/blob/master/tokens.go

Comment: Regarding Option 2: Is there any reason not to store the base64 encoded hash?

Comment: I like option 1, could you show us how i would decode the token to get the hased token that we stored?

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Please don't do this, it's **not secure**!. Use an existing authentication library or design a better approach.

### Explaination

Authentication mechanisms can be tricky to implement properly.

Since these tokens are for authentication purposes, you don't just want them to be **unique**, you also need them to be **unguessable**. An attacker should not be able to calculate a users authentication token.

Your current implementation uses the users email address as the secret input for bcrypt. bcrypt was designed as a secure password hashing algorithm and is hence quite computationally expensive to run. Hence you probably don't want to be doing this in every request.

More importantly, your tokens are **not secure**. If I know your algorithm then I can generate a token for anyone by simply knowing their email address!

Also, with this approach, you cannot revoke or change a compromised token as it is calculated from the users email address. This is also a major security concern.

There are a few different approaches you could take, depending on whether you need stateless authentication or the ability to revoke tokens.

Additionally, as a matter as good practice, authentication/session tokens should not be placed in a URL as it is much easier for these to accidentally *leak* (e.g. cached, available to proxy servers, accidentally stored in browser history etc).

### Identifiers Only?

If you aren't using your tokens for authentication then simply use a hash function on a users email address. For example, [Gravatar](https://www.gravatar.com/) that calculate the `MD5` of a the users lowercase email address and use this to uniquely identify a user. For example:

```
func GravatarMD5(email string) string {
    h := md5.New()
    h.Write([]byte(strings.ToLower(email)))
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
 }
```

There is an infinitesimal chance of a hash collision (and hence not *guaranteed* to be unique) but obviously in a real life implementation this hasn't been an issue.

Comment: Surely this is secure – it's just an expensive way to create a unique email verification token, no? Its not an authentication Bearer token sent on every request.

Comment: The original question asked how to generate tokens to authenticate users, not create email verification tokens.