# How to extract character from array in golang?

Tags: arrays, go

need to extract the random characters from string

here is what i got:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  b := make([]byte, 1)
for i := range b {
    b[i] = letterBytes[rand.Intn(len(letterBytes))]
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

but it always returns "X"
but, i need to return every time new character using rand function.
any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What was the problem?

Comment: Thanks. just updated the query .. please suggest

Comment: Another thing to note is in Go we can have UTF-8 characters and one single byte is not enough to hold those characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang/31832326#31832326)

Comment: no. it always gives the same output. plz see code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a90bdbd0ec0770b373890286322d9063

Comment: see my comment below, it won't work on play.golang.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by seeding the pseudorandom number generator. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    b := make([]byte, 7)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letterBytes[rand.Intn(len(letterBytes))]
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Output:

```
jfXtySC
```

---

> [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org)
>
> About the Playground
>
> In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC
>   (determining the significance of this date is an exercise for the
>   reader). This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them
>   deterministic output.

Therefore, in the Go playground, `time.Now().UnixNano()` always returns the same value. For a random seed value, run the code on your computer.

---

For any Unicode code point (Go rune),

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    chars := []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ世界!@=")
    r := make([]rune, 50)
    for i := range r {
        r[i] = chars[rand.Intn(len(chars))]
    }
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

Output:

```
世QRYSp=@giJMIKly=tXRefjtVkeE!yHhTSQHvLyUYdRNIBbILW
```

Comment: thanks. i added the code as you mentioned . but it always outputs "Bb"

Comment: here is the updated code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a90bdbd0ec0770b373890286322d9063

Comment: @user2315104: See the comment about the Go plaground in my revised answer.

Comment: can this logic be applicable to special characters as well ?

Comment: @user2315104: Use `rune` instead of `byte`. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need cryto/rand. Just set the seed to something different each time. The math/rand package is deterministic with the same seed, so you just need to change the seed each time. Assuming this is not super secure, just add this line.

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
```

Also note if you're using play.golang.org to test it that's not going to work because the time pkg doesn't work there. It'll work fine anywhere else.

If you actually want a random selection of characters though, use crypto/rand.Read NOT a homemade version - you can encode it if you need it within a given character range. Finally, don't roll your own crypto, just in case that's what you're doing here.

Comment: can this logic be applicable to special characters as well ?