# Efficient way to to generate a random Hex string of a fixed length in Golang?

Tags: string, performance, go, random, hex

I need to generate a lot of a random hex string of a fixed length. 
I find this solution [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832326/710955)

I'm doing something like this:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdef0123456789"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())

// RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc ...
// Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832326/710955
func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}

var tryArr = make([]string, 10000)
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    tryArr[i] = RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(8)
}
```

But I got this panic error

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 36 [running]:
math/rand.(*rngSource).Int63(0x11bb1300, 0x8, 0x8)
    D:/Applications/Go/src/math/rand/rng.go:231 +0xa0
main.RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(0x8, 0x11f81be8, 0x8)
    main.go:60 +0x5f
```

The errror seem to be in  `for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0;`, but I don't find why there is this error.

What is the fastest and simplest way to generate a lot of a random hex string of a fixed length in Go?

**Benchmark**

```
package bench

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

const letterBytes = "abcdef0123456789"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 4                    // 4 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

var src1 = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
var src2 = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

// RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc returns a random hexadecimal string of length n.
func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc1(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src1.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src1.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}

func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc2(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, (n+1)/2) // can be simplified to n/2 if n is always even

    if _, err := src2.Read(b); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return hex.EncodeToString(b)[:n]
}

func BenchmarkRandStringBytesMaskImprSrc1(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc1(8)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRandStringBytesMaskImprSrc2(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc2(8)
    }
}


goos: windows
goarch: 386
BenchmarkRandStringBytesMaskImprSrc1-4          20000000               116 ns/op              16 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkRandStringBytesMaskImprSrc2-4          10000000               231 ns/op              24 B/op          3 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  5.139s
```

=> icza `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc`solution is more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the code you posted runs, as even though there's a mistake in it (see below), it still doesn't cause a panic (just makes performance worse).

The stack trace you posted indicates error in the `math/rand` package, I did not experience it. Please post full code and Go version + env (`go version` and `go env`).

#### Reason for panic / Solution:

As it turns out, the asker was calling `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` concurrently, from multiple goroutines. `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` uses a shared `rand.Source` instance which is not safe for concurrent use, hence the panic from the `math/rand` package. Fix is to create a separate `rand.Source()` for each goroutines, and pass that to `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()`.

---

There is a mistake in the "configuration" constants at the beginning:

```
const letterBytes = "abcdef0123456789"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)
```

The constant `letterIdxBits` should contain how many bits are required to represent a symbol index. Since you're using an alphabet of 16 elements (the length of `letterBytes`), 16 combinations require only 4 bits:

```
letterIdxBits = 4                    // 4 bits to represent a letter index
```

Example testing it:

```
var tryArr = make([]string, 10)
for i := range tryArr {
    tryArr[i] = RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(8)
}
fmt.Println(tryArr)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j_c4BDoIUw)):

```
[d3e7caa6 a69c9b7d c37a613b 92d5a43b 64059c4a 4f08141b 70130c65 1546daaf fe140fcd 0d714e4d]
```

(Note: since the starting time on the Go playground is fixed and output is cached, you will always see these random generated strings. Run it on your machine to see random results.)

Comment: I got same panic error with correction if I do `var tryArr = make([]string, 100000)`. I use `go version go1.8.3 windows/386`. Rem No error on Go Playground, strange ....

Comment: @LeMoussel As stated in the answer, the panic does not originate from the code you posted, but from the `math/rand` package. Maybe your installation is corrupted? Can you try it with Go 1.9.1?

Comment: Same with Go v1.9.1. No error with `RandStringBytesMaskImpr` thant don't use `rand.Source`.

Comment: @LeMoussel In that case I suggest to file a bug report, as this is definitely not normal: https://github.com/golang/go/issues

Comment: @LeMoussel One last question: you don't call `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` concurrently from multiple goroutines right? As the code uses a "shared" `rand.Source` which is not safe for concurrent use. If you need concurrent use, create a separate `rand.Source` for each goroutines.

Comment: Yep I call `RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc()` concurrently from multiple goroutines. OK I  create a separate `rand.Source` for each goroutines.

Answer (score 7):

*math/rand.Rand is an io.Reader, so it is trivial to read N random bytes and then hexencode them:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var src = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func main() {
    fmt.Println(RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(4))
}

// RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc returns a random hexadecimal string of length n.
func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, (n+1)/2) // can be simplified to n/2 if n is always even

    if _, err := src.Read(b); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    return hex.EncodeToString(b)[:n]
}
```

Comment: Dont' run ! Error: `src.Read undefined (type rand.Source has no field or method Read)`  [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/D1gSxGbiCC)

Comment: solution is to replace `rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())` by `rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))`

Comment: Also, this needs the library `"time"`

Answer (score 2):

First, replace your rand source with a proper generator, with:

```
var rnd = rand.New(src)
```

Then just use a standard solutions to format numbers:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%x", rnd.Uint64())
```

alternatively;

```
strconv.FormatUint(rnd.Uint64(), 16)
```

Both those methods are faster than yours (after it has been bugfixed):

```
BenchmarkRandStringBytesMaskImprSrc-4       10000000           196 ns/op
BenchmarkFmt-4                              10000000           148 ns/op
BenchmarkStrconv-4                          20000000            89.8 ns/op
```

Comment: Does  `BenchmarkFm()` is bench of `fmt.Sprintf("%x", rnd.Uint64())` & `BenchmarkStrconv()` is bench of `strconv.FormatUint(rnd.Uint64(), 16)`
Can you post benchmark code?

Comment: @LeMoussel Standard benchmarks from the testing package.