# Why having a default clause in a goroutine's select makes it slower?

Tags: go

Referring to the following benchmarking test codes:

```
func BenchmarkRuneCountNoDefault(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    var strings []string
    numStrings := 10
    for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
        s := RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(10)
        strings = append(strings, s)
    }
    jobs := make(chan string)
    results := make (chan int)

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++{
        go RuneCountNoDefault(jobs, results)
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        go func(){
            for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
                <-results
            }
            return
        }()

        for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
            jobs <- strings[n]
        }
    }

    close(jobs)
}

func RuneCountNoDefault(jobs chan string, results chan int){
    for{
        select{
        case j, ok := <-jobs:
            if ok{
                results <- utf8.RuneCountInString(j)
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkRuneCountWithDefault(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    var strings []string
    numStrings := 10
    for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
        s := RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(10)
        strings = append(strings, s)
    }
    jobs := make(chan string)
    results := make (chan int)

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++{
        go RuneCountWithDefault(jobs, results)
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        go func(){
            for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
                <-results
            }
            return
        }()

        for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++{
            jobs <- strings[n]
        }
    }

    close(jobs)
}


func RuneCountWithDefault(jobs chan string, results chan int){
    for{
        select{
        case j, ok := <-jobs:
            if ok{
                results <- utf8.RuneCountInString(j)
            } else {
                return
            }
        default: //DIFFERENCE
        }
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())

func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}
```

When I benchmarked both the functions where one function, `RuneCountNoDefault` has no `default` clause in the `select` and the other, `RuneCountWithDefault` has a `default` clause, I'm getting the following benchmark:

```
BenchmarkRuneCountNoDefault-4             200000              8910 ns/op
BenchmarkRuneCountWithDefault-4                5         277798660 ns/op
```

Checking the `cpuprofile` generated by the tests, I noticed that the function with the `default` clause spends a lot of time in the following channel operations:

[image]

Why having a default clause in the goroutine's `select` makes it slower?

I'm using Go version `1.10` for `windows/amd64`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
>
> If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that
>   can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.
>   Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>   is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>   of the communications can proceed.

---

Modifying your benchmark to count the number of proceed and default cases taken:

```
$ go test default_test.go -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkRuneCountNoDefault-4         300000          4108 ns/op
BenchmarkRuneCountWithDefault-4           10     209890782 ns/op
--- BENCH: BenchmarkRuneCountWithDefault-4
    default_test.go:90: proceeds 114
    default_test.go:91: defaults 128343308
$
```

While other cases were unable to proceed, the default case was taken 128343308 times in 209422470, (209890782 - 114*4108), nanoseconds or 1.63 nanoseconds per default case. If you do something small a large number of times, it adds up.

---

`default_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
    "testing"
    "time"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func BenchmarkRuneCountNoDefault(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    var strings []string
    numStrings := 10
    for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
        s := RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(10)
        strings = append(strings, s)
    }
    jobs := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go RuneCountNoDefault(jobs, results)
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        go func() {
            for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
                <-results
            }
            return
        }()

        for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
            jobs <- strings[n]
        }
    }

    close(jobs)
}

func RuneCountNoDefault(jobs chan string, results chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case j, ok := <-jobs:
            if ok {
                results <- utf8.RuneCountInString(j)
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

var proceeds ,defaults uint64

func BenchmarkRuneCountWithDefault(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()
    var strings []string
    numStrings := 10
    for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
        s := RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(10)
        strings = append(strings, s)
    }
    jobs := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
        go RuneCountWithDefault(jobs, results)
    }
    b.StartTimer()

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        go func() {
            for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
                <-results
            }
            return
        }()

        for n := 0; n < numStrings; n++ {
            jobs <- strings[n]
        }
    }

    close(jobs)

    b.Log("proceeds", atomic.LoadUint64(&proceeds))
    b.Log("defaults", atomic.LoadUint64(&defaults))

}

func RuneCountWithDefault(jobs chan string, results chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case j, ok := <-jobs:

            atomic.AddUint64(&proceeds, 1)

            if ok {
                results <- utf8.RuneCountInString(j)
            } else {
                return
            }
        default: //DIFFERENCE

            atomic.AddUint64(&defaults, 1)

        }
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang
const letterBytes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const (
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

var src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())

func RandStringBytesMaskImprSrc(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    // A src.Int63() generates 63 random bits, enough for letterIdxMax characters!
    for i, cache, remain := n-1, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DLnAY0hovQG