# rand.Intn generating same random sequences multiple time

Tags: go, random-seed

I am trying to write a function that generates a random sequence with an alphanumeric character, Unfortunately, the function returns the same random sequence when calling multiple times.

I even tried by seeding the rand with **time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()**, even though getting the same values again and again

**Main Package:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "userpkg/random"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(random.RandomHash(32))
    fmt.Println(random.RandomHash(32))
    fmt.Println(random.RandomHash(32))
    fmt.Println(random.RandomHash(32))
}
```

**Random Package**

```
package random

func RandomHash(length int8) string {

        rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    pool := []byte(`0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`)

    /* allocate a new slice array to store the hash */
    buf := make([]byte, length)

    for i := int8(0); i < length; i++ {
        buf[i] = pool[rand.Intn(len(pool))]
    }
    rand.Shuffle(len(buf), func(i, j int) {
        buf[i], buf[j] = buf[j], buf[i]
    })
    str := string(buf)
    return str

}
```

Output :

```
Aau9hmA3YpDezPMIFUtgSUoQfwi7KuWK
Aau9hmA3YpDezPMIFUtgSUoQfwi7KuWK
Aau9hmA3YpDezPMIFUtgSUoQfwi7KuWK
Aau9hmA3YpDezPMIFUtgSUoQfwi7KuWK
```

Please guide me on how to solve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to seed the [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package once only. If you call the `RandomHash()` function "very fast", you will seed it to the same value, so it will use the same random values, resulting in the same result! On top of this, on the Go Playground the time is deterministic (it doesn't elapse unless e.g. `time.Sleep()` is called!).

Move the seeding outside of `RandomHash()`, e.g. to a package `init()` function:

```
func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

func RandomHash(length int8) string {
    // ...
}
```

Then each return value of `RandomHash()` will (likely) be different, e.g. (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L1AK97lgf0-)):

```
Aau9hmA3YpDezPMIFUtgSUoQfwi7KuWK
8XhJlp6EAXqqbEcPLQL83pw8wUiJRl7D
HGWpHldhGWpzl2KY10ua15T04N1eoPp7
huRNzf4eD7IIuqYNjoMZB5z6r0RFRB64
```

Also see related question:

[How to generate a random string of a fixed length in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-go/31832326#31832326)

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda, also note that if you need randomess in a more strict sense of that term, you need [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) as `math/rand` is a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) which actually has a property of generating the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers given the same seed.