# Const initializer 'protoimpl.EnforceVersion(20 - protoimpl.MinVersion)' is not a constant

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, grpc-go

I'm new to gRPC, trying to generate go code from protos and getting this error on the generated file

Generated code with issue:

```golang
//  protoc-gen-go v1.25.0
//  protoc        v3.12.3
const (
    // Verify that this generated code is sufficiently up-to-date.
    _ = protoimpl.EnforceVersion(20 - protoimpl.MinVersion)
    // Verify that runtime/protoimpl is sufficiently up-to-date.
    _ = protoimpl.EnforceVersion(protoimpl.MaxVersion - 20)
)
```

Error

```
Const initializer 'protoimpl.EnforceVersion(protoimpl.MaxVersion - 20)' is not a constant
```

Versions:

```sh
$ sw_vers                                                                                                                                                                                                 (sadc1c/opsvisibility)
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.3
BuildVersion:   19D76

$ go version
go version go1.14 darwin/amd64

$ protoc --version                                                                                                                                                                                        (sadc1c/opsvisibility)
libprotoc 3.12.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Golang allow const maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984320/why-doesnt-golang-allow-const-maps)

Comment: The linked duplicate explains what can be used as a constant. Functions cannot (except for a few builtins). Use a `var` stanza instead.

Comment: It's not a code i've written, it's generated by the protoc tool

Comment: Ah, fair point. Duplicate flag retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was a bad version of the package `google.golang.org/protobuf`
The solution is to get the latest version

`go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/proto`

Source: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#enforce-version

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer! This is still the solution in 2024