# Why can't we declare a map and fill it after in the const?

Tags: go, constants

Just why... why does this generate an error?
Is it because it reallocates the map to allow the extension or just because the compiler parser is not meant to handle these cases?

```
const (
        paths = &map[string]*map[string]string {
            Smith: {
                "theFather": "John",
            },
        }
        paths["Smith"]["theSon"] = paths["Smith"]["theFather"] + " Junior"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) are called *constants* for a reason: you expect them to be just that: *constant*.

The *type* defines what operations you may perform on a value of that type. The [map](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) type in Go is not constant, you can change its key-value pairs after its creation, so you cannot have `map` constants.

Your "palette" to choose constants from is defined in the Spec: Constants:

> There are *boolean constants*, *rune constants*, *integer constants*, *floating-point constants*, *complex constants*, and *string constants*.

See related question: [Declare a constant array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137463/declare-a-constant-array/29365828#29365828)

Workaround is simple: declare it to be a variable instead of a constant.