# Why can a const initializer not be nil?

Tags: go

I have a type `A` that is basically a simple map:

```
type A map[int32]struct{}
```

Now, I would like to have a special value of this type to be able to treat it a bit differently. I thought that it would be smart to use `nil` for this propose (additionally, this way, all non initialized variables of type `A` would have this value, and this is also what I would like to have):

```
const s A = nil
```

But I got

> const initializer cannot be nil

Sure I can accept this and refactor my program in dozens of different ways. But I'm still wondering why it's impossible to initialize `const` to `nil`? There must be an architectural reason but I don't see it.

(Note that I prefer to "rename" `nil` instead of using it directly only because the name `nil` is not very intuitive in my case.)

Comment: Even if a const initializer could be nil, your A cannot be const. Const in Go works different. Read https://blog.golang.org/constants and the language spec.

Comment: OK, thanks @Volker, it makes sense now. We can't have const of something that is "pointer-like". The only thing that confuse me is the error messages. Basically, I can't have a const of pointer but only because there is no way to initialize it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why can't we declare a map and fill it after in the const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529691/why-cant-we-declare-a-map-and-fill-it-after-in-the-const/42529986#42529986); [Declare a constant array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137463/declare-a-constant-array/29365828#29365828)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that it is because you can only have constants of type `boolean`, `rune`, `integer`, `floating-point`, `complex`, and `string`.
Docs: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

Whereas `nil` is a zero-value for types `pointer`, `interface`, `map`, `slice`, `channel` and `function`
Docs: https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value

You can read more here https://blog.golang.org/constants