# Best way to init an unchanging byte slice

Tags: go, constants, slice

In Go, you can initialise a byte slice as follows ([try it on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tDO1hgJ6dj9))

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
)

// doStuff will be called many times in actual application, so we want this to be efficient
func doStuff() {
    transparentGif := []byte("GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff" +
        "\xff\xff\xff\x21\xf9\x04\x01\x0a\x00\x01\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00" +
        "\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x4c\x01\x00\x3b\x00")
    // This will be returned by a web service in actuality, but here we just hex dump it    
    fmt.Printf("Your gif is\n%s\n", hex.Dump(transparentGif))
}

func main() {
    doStuff()
}
```

In this case, the data does not need to change, so it would have been nicer (and hopefully more efficient) to initialise it as a constant, near to the function it actually gets used in.

However, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137463/declare-a-constant-array) makes clear, there is no such thing as a const slice in Go.

Is there a more efficient way to do this while keeping the scope small? Ideally with the concatenation and memory allocation done once only.

As far as I know, I'd have to create the slice outside of the function scope then pass it in as a parameter, i.e. widen the scope.

Comment: The answer to the same question you linked says you may create a _variable_ of slice type. Isn't that a good fit for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `transparentGif` as a package-level variable and use that variable in the function.

```
var transparentGif = []byte("GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff" +
        "\xff\xff\xff\x21\xf9\x04\x01\x0a\x00\x01\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00" +
        "\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x4c\x01\x00\x3b\x00")

func doStuff() {
    fmt.Printf("Your gif is\n%s\n", hex.Dump(transparentGif))
}
```

This does add a declaration to the package scope, but is otherwise  neat and tidy. Callers of `doStuff` are forced to know about this detail if an argument is added as suggested in the question.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Implied in your answer, but perhaps worth calling out specifically - 
that the `var` construct works within package scope. The `:=` style does _not_ work in package scope.